# How do I create a "subject" F# Observable?

Tags: f#, observable

In Rx, I can create a subject (something) like this:

```
let s = new Subject<int>()

let subscription = 
  s.Subscribe (fun x -> 
    Console.WriteLine x
  )

s.OnNext 123
```

The subject is both observable and an observer. This is useful when turning callbacks into streams.

What is the equivalent using F#'s built-in `Observable` module?

Comment: Just to make that clear: Using F# does not mean you should avoid using Rx; F# does not have an Rx "alternative" built in. As mentioned in another comment, `FSharp.Control.Reactive` is a wrapper to make Rx friendlier to use from F#.

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev I thought Observable module was a (smaller) alternative to Rx?

Comment: It looks like it is. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an example implementation on F# Snippets:

[Observable.Subject](http://www.fssnip.net/2E/title/ObservableSubject)

> The Subject type implements both IObserver and IObservable. It is functionally equivalent to the type of the same name in the Reactive Extensions (Rx) library.

```ml
module Observable

open System
open System.Collections.Generic

type Subject<'T> () =
   let sync = obj()
   let mutable stopped = false
   let observers = List<IObserver<'T>>()
   let iter f = observers |> Seq.iter f
   let onCompleted () =
      if not stopped then
         stopped <- true
         iter (fun observer -> observer.OnCompleted())
   let onError ex () =
      if not stopped then
         stopped <- true
         iter (fun observer -> observer.OnError(ex))
   let next value () =
      if not stopped then
         iter (fun observer -> observer.OnNext(value))
   let remove observer () =
      observers.Remove observer |> ignore
   member x.Next value = lock sync <| next value
   member x.Error ex = lock sync <| onError ex
   member x.Completed () = lock sync <| onCompleted
   interface IObserver<'T> with
      member x.OnCompleted() = x.Completed()
      member x.OnError ex = x.Error ex
      member x.OnNext value = x.Next value
   interface IObservable<'T> with
      member this.Subscribe(observer:IObserver<'T>) =
         observers.Add observer
         { new IDisposable with
            member this.Dispose() =
               lock sync <| remove observer
         }

do  let s = Subject()
    use d = s.Subscribe(fun x -> sprintf "%d" x |> Console.WriteLine)
    [1..12] |> Seq.iter s.Next
```

Comment: I fixed your link, please make sure it points to the correct place. Btw, does this meet the request for utilizing the builtin `Observable` module.

Comment: Thanks, the editor put "http" in front of my link. It is correct now.

Comment: I don't think the built-in Observable module provides this; thus, the helpful snippet posted by Phillip Trelford.

Comment: `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>` has a built-in alias so you don't have to open the namespace `ResizeArray<'t>`

Answer (score 2):

You said it:

> The subject is both observable and an observer.

To achieve the equivalent of the `Rx.NET` implementation, you'll have to provide the missing parts that make up the `Subject` interface yourself.

All the values in the [`Observable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/control.observable-module-%5Bfsharp%5D) module create an  `IObserver` or return at most two `IObservable`s; it doesn't deal with `Subject`s.

Comment: If you don't like using `System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject` directly, you could use the `FSharp.Control.Reactive` nuget package and write `Subject<int>.broadcast`. It contains a lot of F# style functions for observables (although in this case I personally find it odd that what looks like a property is more of a constructor).